# I have a LaCie external hard drive. I do not find drivers on their website. How do I initialize the drive? Do I add commands in terminal mode?

Tags: hard-drive

I have a LaCie external hard drive.  It apparently is not plug and play.  There are no Debian or other drivers on their website.  Are there instructions that I need to add in terminal mode to get this new drive recognized?

Answer (score 0):

Plug and play devices don't need a driver. That's why they are plug and play. The driver is on the HD. There is an other thing, you have to
[mount](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Mount/USB) it.